# How to do http.get request with Angular 2 and Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am doing an Ionic 2 app. It uses Angular 2.

When doing http request with a server using http, it works.

When I try to get access to a server using https, it does not. I get a javascript alert saying the the "access to https://... not allowed"

That server, when using a regular web browser, gives that warning:

[image]

Then you click advanced and click on "Proceed to 10.97.222.210 (unsafe)".

So here my question:

Is there a special Angula 2 http.get() for https request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This warning (ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID) means that your server need the appropriate certificate to validate https requests.

Try this if you think it's not a problem of certificate:

`run > CMD > ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: if it needs the appropriate certificate, where, in my Ionic app, I will put that certificate and how I will send it to the server? Under config.xml?

Comment: You can't manage certificates in your Ionic app, they aren't on the client side, they are on the server side.
https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/

Comment: Ok, but if you had to write a Ionic app that needs to connect to the server that I am using right now, what would you do to go through?

Comment: Contact the admin of the server and ask him to install the good certificates, there is nothing else to do for that :/

Comment: I just got more info about that certificate. To avoid the warning page, the server needs to have an IP within a certain range (ex: 10.224.5.21 to 10.224.5.26) or I need to map, in my hosts file, an IP address to xxx.servername.net. It is working on Windows or Linux, but how can I do it on a phone?